# How do I create a resource group in Azure using RESTful API in PowerShell?

Tags: rest, powershell, azure

I want to create an Azure Resource Group using a REST API call, but I can't seem to get the syntax right. Here's what I have:

```
$validateResourceGroupUri = 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/SUBSCRIPTION_ID/resourceGroups/' + $resourceGroupName + '/?api-version=2015-01-01'

try { $trapValidateResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method PUT -Headers $armHeaders -Uri $validateResourceGroupUri -Body $deploymentTemplate }
catch { throw $_ }
```

Where:

```
$deploymentTemplate = JSON deployment template (obviously)

$resourceGroupName = user-inputted RG name to be created

$armHeaders = @{ 'Authorization' = "Bearer $token"; 'Content-Type' = "Application/json" }
```

I have a feeling the issue resides in the -Body parameter, but I can't seem to find anything online detailing what exactly the call should consist of. I found [**THIS**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-rest-api) where, if you scroll down to "Create a resource group" section, it details some information, but that's unfortunately all I've been able to find. Any thoughts?

Comment: What is the error message you're getting? Please share the contents of deployment template as well.

Comment: Are you trying to deploy a template to an existing RG, or trying to create an empty RG? If deploying a template, you should deploy to an existing RG. If creating empty RG, the body should not contain any template but the RG definition like in the link you specified under 'Create a resource group'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to use the following commands to create a new resource group, it works for me.

```
##get token
$TENANTID="<your tenantid>"
$APPID="<>"
$PASSWORD="<>"
$result=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TENANTID/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0 -Method Post -Body @{"grant_type" = "client_credentials"; "resource" = "https://management.core.windows.net/"; "client_id" = "$APPID"; "client_secret" = "$PASSWORD" }
$token=$result.access_token

##set subscriptionId and resource group name
$subscriptionId="<your subscriptionId >"
$resourcegroupname="<resource group name>"

$Headers=@{
  'authorization'="Bearer $token"
  'host'="management.azure.com"
}
$body='{
    "location": "northeurope",
     "tags": {
        "tagname1": "test-tag"
    }
 }'
Invoke-RestMethod  -Uri "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourcegroups/${resourcegroupname}?api-version=2015-01-01"  -Headers $Headers -ContentType "application/json" -Method PUT -Body $body
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this works out exactly as I had envisioned!