# How to update or create resource group tags using API in PowerShell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

How can we update or add new tags to the resource group using API.
I have tried the below API in Postman with PUT method. But its removing the first two tags and adding new tags.

https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx?api-version=2021-04-01

Can any one help me out what's wrong with this API.

Thank you.

Comment: You can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68564399/how-to-add-tags-to-existing-azure-resources-using-powershell, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44854649/how-do-i-create-a-resource-group-in-azure-using-restful-api-in-powershell, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59384983/create-update-tags-in-azure-using-api

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please  [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the above  issue you can try the below solution with `PATCH` method.

Basically `PUT` is for checking if resource is exists then update , else create new resource. `PATCH` is always for update a resource .

*When we try with PUT method facing the same which will remove the existing tag and adding the new tag.*

***Try the below API with PATCH method and add in body as shown below:-***

```
https://management.azure.com//subscriptions/subscriptionid/resourceGroups/rgname/providers/Microsoft.Resources/tags/default?api-version=2021-04-01
```

***BEFORE ADDING TAG:-***
[image]

***ADDING BELOW IN PARAMS***:
[image]

***CHANGE BELOW IN AUTHORIZATION:-***
[image]

In body add properties in below `json` format

```
{
"operation": "merge",
  "properties": {
    "tags": {
      "ajtagsss": "newtagtestsss"
     
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

After that send request which will return 200.

[image]

***AFTER ADDING TAGS TO RESOURCE GROUP:-***

[image]

For more information please refer this [***SO THREAD***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59384983/create-update-tags-in-azure-using-api) as suggested by @MadhurajVadde-MT in comment.