# How to modify image tag on azure container registry via rest API?

Tags: azure, containers, docker-registry

Probably I am not able to follow the azure docs quickly, every single time when I try to implement something from azure API, it is always frustrating me. I feel like an idiot. This feeling I have every time when read azure docs. I.e I want to modify or add a new tag azure container registry and here is the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/containerregistry/tag/update-attributes). Could someone understand what is the new tag or what will be modified?

```
curl -SsLf -XPATCH -H "Authorization:Basic $TOKEN"  "https://my.azurecr.io/acr/v1/myrepo/_tags/latest"
```

I am trying to retag the `latest` tag as `123456789`. Any idea how can I handle this?

The response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

Comment: The question title is not something which can be answered here, I suggest you change it to match the specific issue.

Comment: Thanks for addressing @PeteKirkham, I edited which is addressing specific issue, right?

Comment: What is the error you re getting ?

Comment: @Thomas just added to Q

Answer (score 0):

For Workround you can use this API to update the tag of container registry(Make sure to pass the existing tag and new tag as well which you are going to update else it will overwrite with new tag).

```
PATCH https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/{registryName}?api-version=2019-05-01
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

***Same you test out using this Microsoft Document : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/containerregistry/registries/update#code-try-0***

Comment: Better You please follow up this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71334865/how-to-update-or-create-resource-group-tags-using-api-in-powershell) me and my colleague has worked on updating the tag of resources few months ago.